# Change the Title Tag of Search Products Page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search, title

Yes, i've seen some answers on different questions but they didn't fit to my situation.

My theme has **title tag** enabled.

The title in the **wp_get_document_title()** function is different than the real title in my Search Page, which is "You Searched For %search% - %site_name%".

I need to translate the title, nothing more. I searched for **You Searched** in *functions_php* and every other *.php* file in woocommerce that has product or search related and couldn't find it.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks !

Comment: Many different plugins and themes can affect these in various ways. It may have nothing to do with WooCommerce - check any SEO plugins you have installed or deactivate all plugins, check the page title, activate one plugin at a time, check the title, to determine which (if any) plugin is setting it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was caused by Wordpress-Plugin Yoast Seo.

Take a look at your mySql-Database, Table wp_options and search for option_name = wpseo_titles

In the "option_value"-Field you can find the "You Searched for"-String and replace it by e.G. "Deine Suche nach"

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce and many themes provide filter hooks to modify various parts of the page, including the title tag.

You can create a custom function to modify the document title using the `document_title_parts` filter hook.

```
function custom_search_page_title($title_parts) {
    if (is_search()) {
        $title_parts['title'] = sprintf(__('You Searched For %s - %s', 'your-text-domain'), get_search_query(), get_bloginfo('name'));
    }
    return $title_parts;
}
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'custom_search_page_title');
```

Replace `your-text-domain` with the text domain of your theme or plugin.

To translate the title, you can use translation functions like `__()`, `esc_html__()`, or `sprintf()` if you need to insert dynamic content like the search query.